# Handling two rows in ng-repeat with same colour for n items

Tags: html, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects which I need to show as list, required design is

[image]

I tried the code below

```css
.odd{
    background-color: grey;
}

.even{
    background-color: #d09683;
}
```

```html
<ion-audio-track track="track" ng-repeat="x in array" ng-if="track.Size!=0">
        <div class="card" ng-class="{'even':$index%2, 'odd':!($index%2)}">
            <div class="row">
              //item prints here
            </div>
          </div>
  </ion-audio-track>
```

but what I got is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below example.

```js
angular.module('AppModal', []).controller('OTASheetCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  }]);
```

```css
.odd{
    background-color: grey;
}

.even{
    background-color: #d09683;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="AppModal" ng-controller="OTASheetCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="x in array">
  <li ng-class="{'even':$index%4<=1, 'odd':$index%4<=3}">
    {{x}}
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all we will apply one `background-color` for all list items.

```
ul li {
  background: blue;
}
```

In second step we will use 2 css selectors that will override background
of specific list items by creating an even pattern:

```
ul li:nth-child(4n + 1),
ul li:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: green;
}
```

**Image Output:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
}

ul li:nth-child(4n + 1),
ul li:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Sabreena In which browser?

Comment: @Sabreena In all windows based browsers its working fine.. Can you give a bit more details?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more solution:

```css
div.card {
    background-color: grey;
}

div.card:nth-child(4n), div.card:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background-color: #d09683;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,works fine,but i have some complicated conditions for each row,due to that i couldn't use this answer!

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1), tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
 background-color: red;
}
tr {
 background-color: grey;
}
```

[check fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JYn7S/133/)